# Set account recovery preference for AWS Cognito User Pool with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cognito, terraform-provider-aws, infrastructure-as-code

In the spirit of infrastructure as code, I've configured an AWS Cognito User Pool via Terraform with the helpful [`aws_cognito_user_pool`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cognito_user_pool.html) resource.

However, I can't seem to locate the argument/config mapping for the account recovery preference under the *MFA and verification* section.

Without specification, it appears that this is my default selection:

> (Not Recommended) Phone if available, otherwise email, and do allow a user to reset their password via phone if they are also using it for MFA.

---

### Goal

I'd like to set this to `Email only` instead, as annotated by the red rectangle in the image below:

[image: aws cognito user pool settings]

Does anyone know what Terraform argument I need to use to achieve this please? None of the options documented in the `aws_cognito_user_pool` resource seem to map to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 year on, I can now answer my own question, due to the newly introduced setting, [account_recovery_setting](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool#account-recovery-setting), of the [aws_cognito_user_pool](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool) resource.

For example, to set the account recovery preference to **email only**, we can do the following:

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "mypool" {
  name = "mypool"

  account_recovery_setting {
    recovery_mechanism {
      name     = "verified_email"
      priority = 1
    }
  }
}
```

This is available since [v3.19.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/releases/tag/v3.19.0) of the AWS provider, as part of this [merged PR](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/12444).

Answer (score 4):

Hi [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1951253/peter-j-langley) , I am using the CloudFormation template for creating the Cognito Configuartion.

With a little bit of modification  and converting to YAML. We can have the **Recovery Settings set to Email only** option. Please find the below code snippet.

```
UserPool:
    Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPool"
    Properties:
      UserPoolName: "test-pool"
      UsernameAttributes: [email]
      AccountRecoverySetting:
        RecoveryMechanisms:
          - Name: "verified_email"
            Priority: 1
      AutoVerifiedAttributes:
        - email
```

This seems to be working for me :)

Note: while trying to incorporate the other option for **"admin_only"** ,AWS geneartes the error *Invalid account recovery setting parameter. Account Recovery Setting cannot use admin_only setting with any other recovery mechanisms.*

Comment: Hey @DHEERAJ. For my understanding: do you mean to say that you've had success with the [aws_cloudformation_stack](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/cloudformation_stack.html) resource? If so, are you able to provide a more complete snippet please?

Comment: Hi @Peter J Langley ,,Resources:UserPool:Type:"AWS::Cognito::UserPool"Properties:UserPoolName:"test"UsernameAttributes:[email]AccountRecoverySetting:RecoveryMechanisms:Name:"verified_email"Priority:1AutoVerifiedAttributes:-emailVerificationMessageTemplate:DefaultEmailOption:CONFIRM_WITH_LINKEmailVerificationSubject:SubjectEmailVerificationMessage:verifyemail {####}Schema:-Name:emailAttributeDataType:StringMutable:falseRequired:trueMfaConfiguration:"OFF"UserPoolTags:Tag:"x" ,,UserPoolClient:Type: "AWS::Cognito::UserPoolClient"Properties:ClientName:"x"GenerateSecret: falseUserPoolId:!RefUserPool

Answer (score 2):

Terraform doesn't support it yet.
But you could use local exec instead:

```
resource "null_resource" "setup_account_recovery_settings" {
  triggers = {
    version = "${var.version_local_exec_account_recovery_settings}"
  }

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "aws cognito-idp update-user-pool --user-pool-id ${aws_cognito_user_pool.userpool.id} --account-recovery-setting 'RecoveryMechanisms=[{Priority=1,Name=verified_email},{Priority=2,Name=verified_phone_number}]' --region ${var.region}"
  }
}
```

But it will wipe out your whole configuration. Instead you could provide full config as a json but why to use terraform than

Comment: _Terraform doesn't support it yet_ - I thought this may have been the case. I'd prefer not to use this local exec escape hatch. I've now raised an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/11220) for this feature request.

Comment: May i know, how to do it for option 
`None - users will have to contact an administrator to reset their passwords`

Comment: The Terraform AWS Provider now has support for this: see [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65104115/1951253) here.

Answer (score 0):

Following the David's idea, if you want to enable the "email only" option, you should to set

```
--account-recovery-setting 'RecoveryMechanisms=[{Priority=1,Name=verified_email}]'
```

Regards,